# Quiero ingresar cada elemento de un array como un registro de cada columna mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Lo que deseo es ingresar cada elemento de un array en un campo de mi base de datos esta es mi estructura ejemplo tabla registro tiene cuatro campos valor1, valor2 valor3, valor4 quiero ingresar los siguientes registros que se generan del siguiente codigo

```
arraynew = array("5878-1","8978-12","2523-1");
$dato1 = "00320555555";
$dato2 = "22/02/2018";
$dato3 = "Maria Mercedes del Barrio";
$dato4 = $arraynew;

$data = array($dato1,$dato2,$dato3,$dato4);

$nuevo = array();
for($i= 0; $i < count($dato4); $i++ ){
    array_push($nuevo, array(
        $data[0],
        $data[1],
        $data[2],
        $data[3][$i]
    ));
}
echo print_r($nuevo);
echo var_dump($nuevo);
```

esta es la estructura de los array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 00320555555 [1] => 22/02/2018 [2] => Maria Mercedes del Barrio [3] => 5878-1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 00320555555 [1] => 22/02/2018 [2] => Maria Mercedes del Barrio [3] => 8978-12 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 00320555555 [1] => 22/02/2018 [2] => Maria Mercedes del Barrio [3] => 2523-1 ) ) 1
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00320555555' (length=11)
      1 => string '22/02/2018' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Maria Mercedes del Barrio' (length=25)
      3 => string '5878-1' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00320555555' (length=11)
      1 => string '22/02/2018' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Maria Mercedes del Barrio' (length=25)
      3 => string '8978-12' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00320555555' (length=11)
      1 => string '22/02/2018' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Maria Mercedes del Barrio' (length=25)
      3 => string '2523-1' (length=6)
```

lo que yo necesito es ingresar cada array ingresarlo en una fila con su correspondiente campo

Answer (score 3):

La lógica general del manejo de base de datos en php es

1. Conectarse a la Base de datos
2. Preparar la consulta que haremos
3. Ejecutar la query con los parámetros que queremos
4. Hacer fetch en los casos que necesitemos

Veamos los ejemplos, en los que me saltaré el manejo de excepciones para simplificar pero tienes que estar consciente de que tienes manejarlas

Usando PDO sería lo siguiente

```
$conn = new pdo("mysql:dbname=basededatos;host=localhost", "usuario", "contraseña");
$query = $conn->prepare(
"INSERT INTO registro(valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4) 
VALUES(:valor1, :valor2, :valor3, :valor4);");
foreach($arraydearrays as $filas){
    foreach($filas as $insertar){
        $params = array(
            ':valor1' => $insertar[0]
            , ':valor2' => $insertar[1]
            , ':valor3' =>$insertar[2]
            , ':valor4' => $insertar[3]
        );
        $query->execute($params);
        // no es necesario un fetch porque los insert no retornan filas
    }
}
```

[Usando mysqli sería muy parecido](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)
Pero el binding es posicional, osea que el primer bind que haces se une con el primer '?' que está en tu sql y así va.

[puedes hacer el ->bind_param de manera más elegante](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli)

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'basededatos');

$query = mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO registro(valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);");

$valor=array();
$query->bind_param('tipodedatodevalor1', $valor[0]);
$query->bind_param('tipodedatodevalor2', $valor[1]);
$query->bind_param('tipodedatodevalor2', $valor[2]);
$query->bind_param('tipodedatodevalor2', $valor[3]); 

foreach($arraydearrays as $filas){
        foreach($filas as $insertar){
//Asignas los valores que quieres insertar a las variables que bindeaste
            $valor = $insertar;
            $query->execute();
            //si quisieras valores de retorno harías $query->bind_result()
            // no es necesario un ->fetch() porque los insert no retornan filas
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias hermano aplicare

Comment: Te comento lo utilize pero solo me guarda el primer valor de cada elemento y he querido implementarlo sin usar PDO

Comment: pasame tu código, ahora no tengo php pero puedo revisar qué error puede haber

Comment: Este es el codigo https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1in9FXcZU2RMZHDixBtaDl6L08WOm6SO1?usp=sharing